# search query performance report where clause error

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to find all removed adgroups and campaigns. My query is as follows:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
  'SELECT Query, Clicks, Cost, Ctr, ConversionRate,' +
  ' CampaignStatus, AdGroupStatus, CostPerConversion, Conversions, CampaignId, CampaignName, AdGroupId, AdGroupName' +
  ' FROM SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT' +
  ' WHERE ' +
      'Impressions > 2' +
      'AND AdGroupStatus = "removed"' +
  ' DURING LAST_7_DAYS', REPORTING_OPTIONS);
```

when commenting out this line `'AND AdGroupStatus = "removed"' +` then the query works.

I tried using `'AND AdGroupStatus CONTAINS "removed"' +` without success.

Can somebody help me with this?

I should be able to filter like mentioned in the documentation. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/search-query-performance-report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have to use the status in capital letters and , so you should whirte: `AND AdGroupStatus = "REMOVED"` not contains.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql

Comment: this and spaces in the beginning of the line in my where clause.